# jquery ui slider scrollbar does not work when div is display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I hide the scroll-pane div by using display: none;

When I click OPEN, it displays the scroll-pane div and the scroll-bar at the bottom of that div does not work properly.

```
$("#open").click(function() {
    $(".scroll-pane").show();
});
```

If I get rid of display: none; on the scroll-pane div css, it displays the div and the scroll-bar works correctly.

here is a jsfiddle showing you how it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/JjaFW/

```
display: none;
```

here is one of it working, but I had to comment out the display: none; http://jsfiddle.net/JjaFW/1/

```
/* display: none; */
```

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to wrap the open button click event around the sizing of the scrollbar, as seen here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8963098

Answer (score 2):

Here it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/8Wj2W/

Use a class with `visibility: hidden` and remove it with `removeClass()`. This allow jQuery to calculate the styling correctly, but let it hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using display: none, try using visibility: hidden, or $("div").hide(); instead.

Comment: tried both, the .hide() does the same as display: none; when I click open, the scrollbar does not work correctly.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle thing?

Comment: Got it to work, I needed to run this function when the link was clicked, and not until then: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8963098